# PHImageManager requestImageForAsset returns a non-nil but incorrect result

Tags: objective-c, xcode, phasset

I have a page view controller which prepares multiple view controllers (and shows one at a time of course). Each view controller loads corresponding asset based on asset's localIdentifier. It works fine most of the time. But, if it tries to load an asset that has been deleted from Camera Roll or Synced albums from Mac, the view controller dismisses automatically. The reason the asset ends up in the array of local identifiers in the first place is the asset for some reason remains in the moments tab in Photos app (but again, it doesn't exist in Camera Roll or the synced albums).

```
// Get the image
PHCachingImageManager *imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeZero;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // iPhone
    targetSize = CGSizeMake(actualSizedImageRect.size.width,actualSizedImageRect.size.height);
} else {
    // iPad
    targetSize = CGSizeMake(2000,2000);
}
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
options.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
options.version      = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError *error, BOOL *stop, NSDictionary *dictionary) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
};
[imageManager requestImageForAsset:self.asset
                             targetSize:targetSize
                            contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit
                                options:options
                          resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                  [self.assetImageView setImage:result]; //iwashere memo when a photo that no longer exists in albums (but in moments) is about to be presented, above result receives an incorrect image. That's probably causing issues with storyboard constraint so the view controller dismisses automatically.
                                  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)){
                                      if (self.asset.playbackStyle == PHAssetPlaybackStyleLivePhoto){
                                          [self.assetImageView setHidden:YES];
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                          }];
```

I have found so far that the result handler above is called several times, and eventually it returns the result containing a different image, whose different dimensions cause a problem with the storyboard. So, the view controller simply dismisses.

If it's returning a nil, I can simply decide not to load it to self.assetImageView, but even when the wrong image is returned, the result is not nil. I want to know if there's a way to figure out if the returned result really belongs to the asset.

Comment: "a page view controller which loads multiple view controllers" It sounds to me like the problem might lie there. A page view controller should load only _one_ view controller: the one being asked for as the next or previous page. Moreover, in a scrolling page view controller, the pages can be _cached_, so that if the situation changes in the data model, the view controller needs to be prepared to cope with that (e.g. in its `viewWillAppear`). Perhaps it would be more helpful if you were to discuss how you deal with that in the page view controller data source methods.

Comment: Maybe my English is wrong, but I have viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController in place so I think I'm using my page view controller right. But, you may be right in that I might have to do something when viewWillAppear. The above is executed in viewDidLoad. Nevertheless, it's curious that the issue occurs only when those 'ghost' images are about to appear. For existing images, I have no issues.

Comment: I understand, but I'm thinking you could get more specific help if you provided more context in which this code is occurring. You have shown some code but you have said nothing about _where_ that code is called! That's pretty useless.

Comment: Also I notice that you are using PHCachingImageManager. That's wrong. You use PHCachingImageManager with a scrollable page full of images, such as a collection view. If this is about paging to images one at a time, you should be using PHImageManager plain and simple.